# is every nonzero eigenvalue's eigenspace finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis

T is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space , for every non-zero eigenvalue a , is its eigenspace always finite-dimensional ?

Comment: You might want to look at compact operators!

Comment: What about the identity operator?

Comment: @quid yes now i realize i asked a stupid question…

Comment: @hctb, we all do from time to time :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quid points out, the identity operator is an easy counterexample to this claim. But there is an import class of operators called the [compact operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) that does have this property. It is an easy exercise to prove that for a compact operator $T$ it holds that $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{ker} (T-\lambda) < \infty$ for a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$.